# Curly brackets (braces) in Node.js 'require' statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I am trying to understand the difference between the two 'require' statements below.

Specifically, what is the purpose of the `{ }`s wrapped around `ipcMain`?

```
const electron = require('electron')

const {ipcMain} = require('electron')
```

They both appear to assign the contents of the `electron` module, but they obviously function differently.

Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 187, accepted):

The second example uses destructuring.

This will call the specific variable (including functions) that are exported from the required module.

For example (functions.js):

```
module.exports = {
   func1,
   func2
}
```

is included in your file:

```
const { func1, func2 } = require('./functions')
```

Now you can call them individually,

```
func1()
func2()
```

as opposed to:

```
const Functions = require('./functions')
```

are called using dot notation:

```
Functions.func1()
Functions.func2()
```

You can read about destructuring [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), it is a very useful part of ES6 and can be used with arrays as well as objects.

Comment: What kind of destructuring happens when I type `{1, 2, 3}` in node REPL and get `3`?

Answer (score 27):

With `const electron = require('electron')`, the `ipcMain` module will be available as `electron.ipcMain`.

With `const {ipcMain} = require('electron')` the `ipcMain` module will be available as `ipcMain`.

This construct is called [*object destructuring*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) and achieves the same as the Python construct

```
from library import ...
```

In its basic form it allows you to refer to the properties of an object directly:

```
var o = {prop1: '1', prop2: 2}
var {prop1, prop2} = o
console.log(prop1) // '1' (same as o.prop1)
console.log(prop2) // 2 (same as o.prop2)
```

Check:

```
const {ipcMain} = require('electron')
const myElectron = require('electron')
const myipcMain = myElectron.ipcMain
console.log(myipcMain===ipcMain) // true
```

You can use the destructuring assignment to import multiple properties of a JavaScript object, e.g.:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron')
```

If you use a property that doesn't exist, this will be set to `undefined` and you won't get an error.

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, doesntExist} = require('electron')
console.log(doesntExist) // undefined
```

See also: *[What does curly brackets in the `var { … } = …` statements do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290981/what-does-curly-brackets-in-the-var-statements-do)*