# ObjectionJS - Group models in a data layer file

Tags: node.js, require, objection.js, fastify

I have a NodeJS app running `fastify` with `fastify-objectionjs`.

For tidiness, I'd like to group all models in a single file called `_main.js`, where I export an array of the models inside the `models` folder.

Since the fastify-objectionjs registration requires an array of models, I thought I could just import the array from my `_main.js` and feed it as it is to the registration function.

But ObjectionJS is telling me that *The supplied models are invalid*.

**/app.js** (node entry point)

```js
const fastify = require('fastify')({
    logger: true
})

const knexConfig = require('./knexfile')
const dataLayer = require('./models/_main')
fastify.register(require('fastify-objectionjs'), {
    knexConfig: knexConfig,
    models: dataLayer
})

// Also tried:
// fastify.register(require('fastify-objectionjs'), {
//     knexConfig: knexConfig,
//     models: [dataLayer]
// })
```

**/models/_main.js**

```js
const User = require('./user.model')

var dataLayer = [User]

module.exports = dataLayer

// Also tried without var:
// module.exports = {
//     dataLayer: [
//         User
//     ]
// }
```

**/models/user.model.js**

```js
const Knex = require('knex')
const connection = require('../knexfile')
const { Model } = require('objection')
const knexConnection = Knex(connection)
Model.knex(knexConnection)

class User extends Model {
  static get tableName () {
    return 'users'
  }
}

module.exports = { User }
```

I can't seem to find a problem in the file flow, but if I create the models array on the fly, the app starts smoothly:

**/app.js** (node entry point)

```js
const fastify = require('fastify')({
    logger: true
})

const knexConfig = require('./knexfile')
const User = require('./models/user.model') // changed
fastify.register(require('fastify-objectionjs'), {
    knexConfig: knexConfig,
    models: [User] // changed
})
```

Any idea why this isn't working?
Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: @Arfost Do you mean it should be `const dataLayer = require('./models/_main.js')` ? That wouldn't explain why `const User = require('./models/user.model')` works without `.js` in the second example. Anyway, I tried requiring `./models/_main.js` right now and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the gotcha, I just needed to use destructuring in the `require` of `User`, like this:

**/models/_main.js**

```js
// BAD
// const User = require('./user.model')

// GOOD
const { User } = require('./user.model')

module.exports = [User]
```

Works like a charm.

Useful question that explains the difference:
[Curly brackets (braces) in node require statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660022/curly-brackets-braces-in-node-require-statement)