# In Node, why does 'require' assignment sometimes require curly brackets?

Tags: node.js, import, requirejs, export

Running some tests through Chai, I noticed the tests would fail under this code:

```
const add = require('./addition');
//'add is not a function error' even though it's directly exported as a function
```

But it would pass under this:

```
const {add} = require('./addition');
```

Yet when using npm modules, everything is declared without the brackets:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var session = require('express-session');
```

And those are essentially objects with multiple properties to be accessed. Why does it work this way? Is it only function exports that must be assigned as objects explicitly?

Comment: You have some explication [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660022/curly-brackets-braces-in-node-require-statement)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is known as object destructuring. Please refer the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring).

For example you have exported a file called sampleFunctions.js which has following functions as exports

```
function function1(params) {};
function function2(params) {};

module.exports = {
sampleFunc1: function1,
sampleFunc2: function2
}
```

Now when you need to require it, there are two ways -

- when you only need one function(using object destructuring)

```
let {sampleFunc1} = require('./sampleFunctions');
sampleFunc1();
```

In this you exposed only the required function not all of the functions exported from that file.

- when you want to require all the functions from that file

```
let sampleFuncs = require('./sampleFunctions');
let samFunc1 = sampleFuncs.sampleFunc1;
samFunc1()
```

Comment: Awesome, didn't realize this. Thanks for the concise answer.