# Difference between const {Hoge} and const Hoge (node.js)

Tags: node.js

I don't understand the difference in the code below. What's the difference?

A:

```
const Hoge = require('@foo/hoge');
```

B:

```
const {Hoge} = require('@foo/hoge');
```

thanks

Comment: I noticed, that this is a duplicate after posting my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660022/curly-brackets-braces-in-node-require-statement

Comment: see [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Curly brackets (braces) in node require statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660022/curly-brackets-braces-in-node-require-statement)

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, `Hoge` becomes assigned to the `module.exports` value from the module

```js
// @foo/hoge entry file
module.exports = {
    Hoge: 123
}

// Your file
const Hoge = require("@foo/hoge")
// Hoge = { Hoge: 123 }
```

In the second example, you take the property `Hoge` out of the object `module.exports`

```js
// Your file
const { Hoge } = require("@foo/hoge")
// Hoge = 123
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I understand the behavior.

Where can I find this in the documentation?
It's hard to find the difference in behavior with the symbols ({} ) ...