# I didn't understand const{} in Node

Tags: node.js, constants, braces

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
```

I'm still new to node.js. I would like to know what's the purpose of the curly braces near const, is it like an angular/typescript way to fetch the object from the module?

Is there any ES6 or whatever new syntax that I should be aware of? 
like:

```
const[foo] = , or const(foo) =
```

Comment: This is destructuring assignment - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290981/what-does-curly-brackets-in-the-var-statements-do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a part of ES6. They are called [named exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) and this accessing method is called "destructuring".

So if you have a module with this contents:

`export const foo = Math.sqrt(2);`

You can use foo by doing any of the below:

`import foo from "module";`

`import { foo } from "module";`

`import * as mod from "module"; console.log(mod.foo)`

Comment: To be clear, `const { exec } = require('child_process')` isn't actually a named export (although it is emulating one); it's just regular destructuring. node doesn't yet have native support for ES6 modules so using destructuring with `require` statements is the next best thing. (Of course, you can use Babel to be able to use the ES6 module syntax.)