# const {children} = this.props vs const children = this.props.children

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm new to react and I'm trying to understand how the general syntax works, not sure if this is an appropriate place to ask this.
The following is my code for a simple title component.

```
export default class Title extends Component { 
    render () {
        const {children} = this.props;

        return (
          <View style={styles.header}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{children}</Text>
          </View>
        )
    }
}
```

is this

`const {children} = this.props;`

is equivalent to

```
const children = this.props.children;
```

If so, which is the correct form to use? Just trying to get a better understanding how react works, in addition, would the following try to get the children of the children of the props?

`const {children} = this.props.children`

Comment: Either of the two ways are valid, it is your preference of which to use. Your last example will not get children, unless children has a property children

Comment: It's the same, you only save one variable assignment in `const { children }` if children is not defined

Comment: This is nothing specific to React. Its a new feature (Object Destructuring) of JS.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: It is important to understand that it is not React/JSX syntax, it's purely Javascript syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does curly brackets in the \`var { ... } = ...\` statements do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290981/what-does-curly-brackets-in-the-var-statements-do)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is called object destructuring and allows you to take properties of an object and store them conveniently into a variable. For example:

```js
const obj = {
 prop1: 1,
 prop2: 2
}

const {prop1, prop2} = obj;

console.log(prop1, prop2);
```

In your example the children property is pulled of the `this.props` object and put into a `const` which is named children.

```
const {children} = this.props;
```

is equivalent to

```
const children = this.props.children;
```

However the object destructuring syntax is more compact and could more easily extended for example if props had a prop called foo:

```
const {children, foo} = this.props;
```

Now we have a variable of both children and foo.

Answer (score 1):

It's called **Object Destructuring**. It is not specific to React

You can extract a property of an Object like so.

This will gives you **undefined**, because **children** doesn't contains a **children** property.

```
const {children} = this.props.children
```

But, both methods are good.

Read this for more informations: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score -1):

When you have an object with just one property such as

```
const obj = {
  propA: 5
}
```

Ther is no big differnce between

`const propA = obj.propA` and `const { propA } = obj`

However, with object which have multiple properties, object destructuring becomes benefitial (we write less sode):

```
const obj = {
  propA: 5,
  propbB: true,
  propC: 'some string'
}

// less code (and cleaner)
const { propA, propB, propC } = obj

// otherwise
const propA = obj.propA
const propB = obj.propB
const propC = obj.propC
```