# Destructuring or Something Different?

Tags: express, ecmascript-6, destructuring

This looks like destructuring:

`const {getElementById, seedElements} = require('./utils')`

but I'm confused about it. I'm used to seeing something like:

`let {first, last} = name`

Are these doing the same things just in different files?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660022/curly-brackets-braces-in-node-require-statement it's the same when used for require / import objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does curly brackets in the \`var { ... } = ...\` statements do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290981/what-does-curly-brackets-in-the-var-statements-do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think

```
const {getElementById, seedElements} = require('./utils')
```

as destructuring since when you export, you would write your export like

```
module.exports = { getElementById, seedElements };
```

or

```
export { getElementById, seedElements };
```

and while importing using require you would basically be importing the entire module and you can destructure the individual modules from it.

```
const {getElementById, seedElements} = require('./utils')
```

would be similar to

```
const Utils = require('./utils');
const { getElementById, seedElements } = Utils;
```

with the import syntax, you would however import the named exports like

```
import { getElementById, seedElements } from './utils';
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is object destructuring.

The [`require()`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require) function in Node.js can be used to import modules, JSON, and local files. For instance (from [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require)):

```
// Importing a local module:
const myLocalModule = require('./path/myLocalModule');
```

Calling `require(moduleId)` returns the object `module.exports` of `moduleId` ( `module.exports` contains precisely all properties that are made available by the module).