# About the correct call of "{variable} = value" method?

Tags: javascript

What is this correct name?
I tried to google it, but I can't find answer what I want.

```
const example = {"house":"foo","owner":"bar"};
var {house} = example;

console.log(house);
```

What is `{house} = example` correct name?

Sorry about my describing, English is not my native language.

Comment: This is called [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Also relevant: [What does curly brackets in the `var { … } = …` statements do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15290981)

Comment: thanks for your answer!